# Using DDD, where is the best pace to put some basic types which are used everywhere in the application

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I want to introduce a calendar booking system to my application, and I have defined the following types:

```
public class TimeRange
{
    public TimeRange()
    {
        Start = End = default;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

public class Calendar
{
    public Calendar()
    {
        Appointments = new List<TimeRange>();
    }

    public List<TimeRange> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

I am also using a review system and for that I have introduced a `StarRating` type

```
// example: 3.5 out of 5 stars
public class StarRating
{
    public StarRating(double rating, int outOf)
    {
        Rating = rating;
        OutOf = outOf;
    }

    public double Rating { get; set; }

    public int OutOf { get; set; }

    // builds HTML code for displaying 3.5 starts out of 5
    public string GetStarRatingHtml(string colorClass = "")
    {
        var starRatingHtml = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < OutOf; i++)
        {
            if (Rating >= (float)(i + 0.75))
            {
                starRatingHtml.Append(GetFullStar(colorClass));
            }
            else if (Rating > (float)(i + 0.25))
            {
                starRatingHtml.Append(GetHalfStar(colorClass));
            }
            else
            {
                starRatingHtml.Append(GetEmptyStar(colorClass));
            }
        }

        TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
        span.Attributes.Add("Title", Rating + " Stars");
        span.InnerHtml = starRatingHtml.ToString();
        return span.ToString();
    }

    private string GetFullStar(string colorClass = "")
    {
        return $"<span class='fa fa-star full-star {colorClass}'></span>";
    }

    private string GetHalfStar(string colorClass = "")
    {
        return $"<span class='fa fa-star-half-o half-star {colorClass}'></span>";
    }

    private string GetEmptyStar(string colorClass = "")
    {
        return $"<span class='fa fa-star-o empty-star {colorClass}'></span>";
    }
}
```

I want to follow DDD guide lines and am not clear where is the best place to put these types?

**1. Should I put them in my domain layer?**

As the domain layer is accessible by all the other layers, I can use these types everywhere in my application. But I don't actually use any of these types in my domain model, as an example I have a `RentalProperty` domain model:

```
public class RentalProperty
{
    public long PropertyId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; } 

    public string ViewingTimes { get; set; } // <-- Contains Calendar class serialized to json string
}
```

**2. If I put these types in domain layer should I create corresponding `ViewModels` in my Application Layer?**

Taking the example above, I have `RentalPropertyViewModel` in my application layer

```
public class RentalPropertyViewModel
{
    public long PropertyId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; } 

    public Calendar ViewingTimes { get; set; } // <-- Should I create CalendarViewModel in application layer?
}
```

**3. Should I treat them as built in types and put them in cross-cutting layer?**

---

Update: I think the main reason for my confusion is that I had decided to store the serialized calendar times as json string in DB, instead of creating a 1-to-many relationship. I have asked this related question: [1-to-many relationship vs json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480959/storing-a-list-into-relational-db-1-to-many-relationship-vs-serialized-json-str)

Comment: I'd put them in the domain layer, but I personally wouldn't want the domain layer to be accessed anywhere outside the application layer. I'd also move the logic out from your `StarRating` for creating html stars into the web ui layer in a view model.

Comment: Thanks, it make sense to move the html part of `StarRating` to application layer.

Comment: Put them wherever you like that makes the most sense to you and your work place, and what works for your system and concerns. DDD and every other design or architectural pattern is completely and entirely opinionated and based on today's fashion sense, and a loose sense of current norms, and what you need to achieve. If you need to ask this question it means you need to think about it more and research it more

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's difficult for you is because you are moving away from DDD principles a bit. You need to refactor your additional concepts into something that makes sense in the ubiquitous language.
Based on your description here's what I'd expect:

**Time Range and Calendar**

1. You can have an entity named Appointment and Appointment will have a value type of "Time Range". You can't have a Time-Range outside of an appointment, it's meaningless. An appointment has a unique key of the date and time of the appointment.
2. Calendar is a value type for a User-Type entity. So, "A user has a calendar" and conversely "calendar cannot exist without a user".

**Star Rating Type**
First off, I would strongly recommend that you get that "build HTML" type things out of that class, into a separate UI type class outside of the domain.
Then, I would expect to see an Entity that is rated. That is, Star Rating will be a value type inside the entity being rated. It cannot exist on it's own outside of an entity. It wouldn't "fit".

Comment: Thanks for your answer... the viewing time belong to the property... because the same user can manage multiple properties but I get what you mean about introducing entities/value-objects in domain layer.

Answer (score 0):

Domain Driven Design from Eric Evans recommends the usage of "at least" the following 4 layers:

**Interfaces**

Your UI tecnologies or HTTP Services like REST and SOAP.

**Application**

It's where you create your application flows consuming the Domain Logics. Where most of people I see are putting their **ViewModels**, to attend a need of a specific flow.

**Domain**

Where you should put your **models** and types that belongs to the domain, surely RentalProperty and StarRating fits better here. Also here you create your Domain **Services**, **interfaces** to invert the dependencies with infrastructure layers and any domain specific code.

**Infrastructure**

Classes like repositories that depends on infrastructure (databases, network, another services, IO).

But remember that DDD is a way of seeing applications and a lot of recommendations, many people use their different details and beliefs in their own DDD implementations.